# Rate app URL - Production vs Closed track

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, url, google-console-developer

I'm adding a "Rate App" pop up to my game.
I'm using a simple "Application.OpenURL", and right now the only URL I have is a URL from the closed track in "Google Play Console". 
I'm assuming the when I will roll out the app to production the URL will be different, am I right? How will I update the URL after roll out? 
Will the URL stay the same? Should I use "Remote settings" to update it? 
What is the best practice for that "Rate app" PopUp?

Thanks, Dror

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL will remain same, you can easily find out your app url for play store which is:

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=${your app package-name}
```

Put your package name as value of id parameter.
You should navigate to user on the above link. that's it.